# Play Framework migration from 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

In plugins.sbt change

From: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.6")`

To: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")`

build.properties change

From:  `sbt.version=0.13.5`
To: `sbt.version=0.13.8`

And have error:

```
    [error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected.
[error] Note that conflicts were resolved for some dependencies:
[error]     org.apache.commons:commons-compress
[error]     org.tukaani:xz
[error]     org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils
[error]     com.google.guava:guava
[error]     org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds
[error]     com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10
[error]     com.typesafe:config
[error]     org.slf4j:slf4j-api
[error]     org.apache.commons:commons-lang3
[error]     org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni
[error]     org.webjars:webjars-locator
[error]     com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-web
[error]     com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Does, some know how fix that?

Comment: You have to check all the related dependencies, it's highly recommended you follow the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24).

Comment: @Vitalli for play 2.4.6 change build.properties in to sbt.version=0.13.9

Comment: @SupunWijerathne that didn't help. but i'm already solved problem. tnx

Comment: @VitaliiShkurenko nice. !!!!! (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with **play2-war-plugin** plugin.
Just change version from: `1.3-beta1` to `1.4-beta1` and project was compile successfully